# Retrieve Application Insights information to .Net app

Tags: .net, azure-application-insights

We are using Application Insights to record Telemetry for our app. I want to write a custom app to display  Telemetry events from Application Insights. Any examples / best practices for such an app? Most examples on the web show how to add to AppInsights from .Net app, not to retrieve from it.

Comment: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/

Comment: Apparently, it is quite easy to do using Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights object. Here is an excellent example by Tobias Zimmergren: https://zimmergren.net/retrieve-logs-from-application-insights-programmatically-with-net-core-c/

However, Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights is deprecated. Is there a more recent library?